# How can I add menu items to the Gnome "Applications" menu from the command line?

Tags: ubuntu, bash, gnome, perl

I'm using Ubuntu 9.10, and I'd like to automate the addition of some menu items the Ubuntu "Applications" menu.

I know that I can use alacarte to make one-off additions, but I'm looking to automate (either via Perl or Bash) the addition of many menu items to this menu.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here's a link](https://web.archive.org/web/20161106081728/http://www.stchman.com/menu_entry.html) for a shell script which will create entries in GNOME's menu

Snippet of the post:

> I have seen this question asked
> frequently on the Ubuntu forums.  This
> page will teach you how.  You as a
> user can make your own menu entry by
> right clicking on the menu icon in the
> upper left corner and selecting Edit
> Menus.  This bring up a GUI an you can
> select which section to install the
> menu item in.  We want to create one
> via a shell script.
>
> All menu items are stored in the
> /usr/share/applications folder.  In
> that folder there will be a .desktop
> file for each menu entry.  Lets get
> into those .desktop files shall we?
>
> Here is an example of the contents of
> a .desktop file: What the following
> code does is make a menu entry called
> Kompozer in the Programming section of
> the Gnome menu.

Comment: Link's dead - it would appear

Answer (score 6):

It should be noted that the alacarte doesn't put the items you add in `/usr/share/applications`. It adds them to your home directory. So if you're *not* wanting to create entries for every user, just the current user, you'll need to make the below changes.

Below is a test entry, added via alacarte, and the resulting files that were created.

(1) The local **applications.menu** file is updated. Note the `<Filename>` entry.

```
# cat /home/user/.config/menus/applications.menu 
<!DOCTYPE Menu
 PUBLIC '-//freedesktop//DTD Menu 1.0//EN'
 'http://standards.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/menu-1.0.dtd'>
<Menu>
<Name>Applications</Name>
<MergeFile type="parent">/etc/xdg/menus/applications.menu</MergeFile>
<Menu>
<Name>Internet</Name>
<Include>
<Filename>alacarte-made.desktop</Filename>
</Include>
</Menu>
</Menu>
```

(2) The **alacarte-made.desktop** file is created in `~/.local/share/applications`.

```
# ls -ltr ~/.local/share/applications/
-rw------- 1 user user  495 2010-04-14 15:48 Nokia-QtCreator.desktop
-rw------- 1 user user  403 2010-04-14 15:48 defaults.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  134 2010-12-20 10:33 userapp-gvim-JYONNV.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  321 2010-12-20 10:33 mimeinfo.cache
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  165 2010-12-20 10:33 mimeapps.list
drwx------ 9 user user 4096 2011-05-26 15:34 ..
-rw------- 1 user user  108 2011-05-26 15:34 installjammer-program.desktop
-rw------- 1 user user  182 2011-05-26 15:34 installjammer-help.desktop
-rw------- 1 user user  201 2011-05-26 15:34 installjammer-userguide.desktop
-rw------- 1 user user  114 2011-05-26 15:34 installjammer-uninstall.desktop
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user user  202 2011-06-10 09:27 alacarte-made.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  202 2011-06-10 09:28 alacarte-made.desktop.undo-0
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 4096 2011-06-10 09:28 .
```

(3) If you look at the contents of `alacarte-made.desktop` you see the "test" entry that was added to my menu.

```
# cat ~/.local/share/applications/alacarte-made.desktop
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open

[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon[en_US]=gnome-panel-launcher
Name[en_US]=test
Exec=secretsync
Name=test
Icon=gnome-panel-launcher
```

I'm not certain the best way to modify the `applications.menu` file in 1 above. It's obviously a specifically formatted file, and I don't know if there is a utility that could be used to make an entry from a script or command-line.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the other answers here have incorrect paths (at least, they do not exist on my Ubuntu 10.10 system) or only address system-level menus. Gnome user-level menus are stored in your $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/menus directory (by default ~/.config/menus/) and $XDG_DATA_HOME/applications directory (by default ~/.local/share/applications). You can manually edit these files. See this [Ubunto Forums thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10615443) for some details; specifically the [Desktop Menu Specification](http://Desktop%20Menu%20Specification) tells more about the files and their format.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the link Sathya provided, this also shows how to automate adding additional menus to the Applications menu:

http://wiki.matusov.sk/howto/gnome-menu-edit